# What will happen if you fired a gun in a room filled with hydrogen gas?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas

Will the room explode? How does it happen?

Comment: you also need oxygen in order to explode, see https://sciencing.com/happens-hydrogen-oxygen-combine-8515474.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because open-ended "What if _____ happened?" are [explicitly off topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

if you fired a gun in a room containing nothing but hydrogen, nothing would happen. for hydrogen to explode it first needs to be mixed with a certain amount of oxygen.

Comment: Nothing would happen except the usual defeningly loud report from the gun, the flash and smoke from the muzzle, and quite possibly substantial damage to whatever target the bullet hit. :-)

Comment: of course. as a shooter, i take all those other things you mention for granted!

Answer (score 1):

To amplify the answer by @nielsnielsen I'll start by repeating that hydrogen by itself is **not** flammable. In order for it to burn you need at least some oxygen. The resulting chemical reaction forms $H_2O$ (water).

In addition, for hydrogen to burn the percentage of hydrogen to oxygen has to be between 4% and 95%. If you use air instead of oxygen, then the ratio is between 4 and 75%. If you want an explosion instead of just burning, the hydrogen to air ratio should be between 18 and 60%. In other words, just about any mixture of hydrogen to air will burn, but explosion is a little bit more exacting. More details are [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8498/how-explosive-is-hydrogen-gas).

Note that the above assumes a thorough mixing of gases. If you just release some hydrogen in a room filled with air (or the reverse), there is guaranteed to be some point where the correct conditions will exist for burning or even an explosion.